# Rewrite search htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm looking for the best way to rewrite a search link. On my site I have:

```
http://domain.com/search.php?keyword=blue+widget&Search=Search
```

I want to end up with this:

```
http://domain.com/blue-widget
```

There's no database, just straight html/css.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something closer to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ search.php?keyword=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ search.php?keyword=$1
```

Jason's answer only work in one example case.

**UPDATE:**

You can add more characters to the regex portion to allow them. For example, to allow `*`, do this:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-*]+)$
```

If someone uses a bad character directly in a URL, you can redirect them to a 404 page. But, if you are calling the URL for the user based on something they type into a form, you can check the value for bad characters before sending them to a URL that will end up on a 404 page and notify the user.

Comment: A dynamic keyword was not relayed in the OP. Nonetheless, if that is the case, this is good provided they do some `keyword` scrubbing.

Comment: That's nice Woz, thanks. If I use a character like * it goes to the host's 404 page, can I adapt this code to go to one of my files such as 404.php or even just strip out the offending character and go to search.php?

Comment: I think you just add whatever characters you want to accept to the regex portion like this: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-*]+)$`. My guess is that it's more secure to specify the characters you accept than to try to ban certain evil characters (white listing vs. black listing).

Comment: I added the extra info to my answer.

Comment: @woz - Did you modify that code? The one above doesn't seem to work for some reason and I don't have the original.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules work the other way around. So the link will be `blue-widget` which will be rewritten to `search.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/blue-widget$ /search.php?keyword=blue+widget&Search=Search [L]
```

**Note:** If you accept additional query string parameters, you will need to use the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) flag.

Comment: I need any search parameter to be changed this way, Jason. Can I use a wildcard on the first and second part of that rule? Ideally I also need some sanitization in there too.

Comment: The example provided by the OP is still valid if the `search.php` links currently exist and need to be `redirected`.  In either case, your answer is needed, but it doesn't rule out the need for the redirect.

Comment: @Sara44, I would encourage you to update your question as that requirement was not relayed.